# Problematic Trigger - on Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a trigger which keeps track of deleted transactions. It stores the before and after transaction record values into a different table called TransHistory. The problem is that when I delete a record it stores not only the deleted record but before that it inserts the top record which exists in my DataGridView for any customer as an update. Here is my Delete trigger:

```
USE [dbPB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[delete_history]    Script Date: 05/28/2013 19:40:13       ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER On
 GO

 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[delete_history] ON [dbo].[Transaction]
 FOR DELETE
 AS
 INSERT TransHistory (CustomerID, TransactionID, Buyin, 
                        Cashout, CreditPaid, Type,
                         Date, action)
 SELECT CustomerID, TransactionID, Buyin, Cashout, 
   CreditPaid, Type, GETDATE(), 'DELETED' 
 FROM deleted
```

and here is my UPDATE trigger:

```
 USE [dbPB]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[update_history]    Script Date: 05/28/2013 20:24:28      ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_history] ON [dbo].[Transaction]
 FOR UPDATE
 AS
 INSERT TransHistory (CustomerID, TransactionID, Buyin, 
                         Cashout, CreditPaid, Type,
                         Date, action)
 SELECT top (1) CustomerID,TransactionID, Buyin, Cashout, CreditPaid, Type,
             GETDATE(), 'BEFORE UPDATE' 
 FROM deleted

 INSERT TransHistory (CustomerID, TransactionID, Buyin, Cashout,
                         CreditPaid, Type, 
                         Date, action)
 SELECT top(1) CustomerID, TransactionID, Buyin, Cashout, CreditPaid, Type,
             GETDATE(), 'AFTER UPDATE' 
 FROM inserted
```

Comment: Have you ran a profiler when deleting a record?

Comment: I'm not sure... this is my first trigger

Comment: So both triggers are executed when you do a `DELETE` ?

Comment: A profiler is a program with which you can see what queries are executed on your SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE trigger gets executed but stores info about an irrelevant record. That record appears at the top of my DataGridView in my Windows form. After that, the correct (deleted) record gets stored successfully...

Comment: Triggers seem fine (except for `top 1` - trigger is called once per update; it makes no sense archiving only one row). Problem might be on client side - the form updates retrieved rows by accident and saves them back. Do you use an ORM? Entity framework or something?

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović Actually I have added the top (1) just as an edit to see if that would work. It wasn't included in my initial code. I am using a DataSet (BindingSource/TableAdapter). Do you think the problem comes from my Fill method which is re-called to refresh the DataGridView after a record has been deleted?

Comment: No. What happens if you delete a record directly from Sql Server Management Studio? If it behaves the same triggers are wrong; if not, the form changes data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking you are sending an update and a delete. I would use profiler to see exaclty what is sent to the database when the trigger gets invoked by a delete. You can try doing a delete statment from SSMS not the application and you will proably see in Profiler that only the delete statement was sent and check the data to see if only the delete trigger fired. Then do the same from theapplication and see that two statments are sent instead of one. At least this will tell you if the problem is the triggers or the application but I'm betting on the application.

Comment: as Nikola and HLGEM stated the triggers work fine. I have deleted a transaction record from the database directly and only the deleted record is stored in the database. Therefore, the application creates the problem. But since I want the latest (updated) info in my datagrid how should I handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, here is the problem. This line of code here which I am using to update the database through the dataset:   Me.TransactionTableAdapter.Update(Me.DbPBDataSet)   Do you guys know what I should use instead to proceed with the updates?

Comment: I'm not an application person, you might want to make a separate question about this to attract the folks who are, but you should be selecting the data for your grid not updating it.